# Material disappeared in 3D view

Tags: materials, 3d-view

When I opened my file today all colors (material) were no longer showing in 3d-view. 
I save a new file every now and then so that I can go back in case I want to make changes. And the material shows in the last one but not in the current one. I've not made any changes in render. So far I've only worked with the mesh and material (only simple colors), mirror modifier and subsurf modifier. What happened? What can I do? Please look at the picture

and it doesn't work to put material on any new object either.

[image]

Comment: Try switching to cycles and back

Comment: thank you, I tried it and the material shows in cycles, but when I go back to render it disappeares again. I've used blender render the whole time

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas. Sounds like a bug, but the BI is dead, so there's no way the devs are going to fix it. You can try downloading the latest 2.79 from builder.blender.org. You could also switch to cycles while working and use the material settings -> Viewport color. That should be a temp. fix.